# Is the sign convention necessary in solving kinematics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, conventions

I have started with kinematics and I have a really basic question of following sign convention i.e taking up and right positive and down and left negative. Is such a convention necessary when I can simply taking a velocity or acceleration as positive or negative depending on if it moves with the body or against it?

Also is the sign convention stated by me is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose any sign convention you want, but you must be diligent to stick to it once you choose it since without a consistent sign convention, you can't get the right answers. In this context, the right sign convention is the one used by the person who grades your homework!

Comment: Will I be getting correct answers if I consider the motion of a body as a reference and considered the signs of motion of other bodies with respect to it. @niels nielsen

Comment: Also if I take the sign convention just like the co-ordinate system will it be helpful? @niels nielsen

Comment: *"In this context, the right sign convention is the one used by the person who grades your homework!"* You shouldn't really joke like that.The correct convention is anyone's as long as he sticks with it. If a grader doesn't get that, he shouldn't be grading!

Comment: I graded a lot of homework while in grad school, and I needed to see the sign conventions. Naturally, if everyone did it the same, it made my job a *lot* easier, especially if I had a hundred assignments to grade.